# insert method for doubly linked list C++

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I am implementing doubly linked list in C++, and I have been trying to make my insert method work without success.
The class should contain two node pointers: one to the head of the list, and one to the tail of the list. If the list is empty, they should both point to nullptr.
The insert method should take a value at given index and add it to the list, increasing its size with one element.  my code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev; //previous node pointer
    Node(int v) : value(v), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    Node *prev;

    Node *get_node(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 or index >= size)
        {
            throw range_error("IndexError: Index out of range");
        }

        Node *current = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        return current;
    }

public:
    int size;
    LinkedList()
    {
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }

    int length()
    {
        Node *current = head;
        int count = 0;

        while (current != nullptr)
        {
            count++;
            current = current->next;
        }

        cout << "Length of list is " << count << endl;
        return count;
    }

    void append(int value)
    {
        Node *new_node = new Node(value);

        if (head == nullptr)
        {
            head = new_node;
            head->prev = nullptr;
            new_node->next = tail;
        }
        else if (tail == nullptr)
        {
            tail = new_node;
            new_node->next = nullptr;
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        Node *current = head;
        Node *prev;
        cout << "[";
        if (current->next == NULL)
        {
            cout << current->value;
            cout << "]";
        }
        else
        {

            while (current->next != nullptr)
            {
                cout << current->value;
                cout << ", ";
                prev = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
            cout << current->value << "]" << endl;
        }
    }

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        Node *current;
        Node *next;

        current = head;

        while (current != nullptr)
        {
            next = current->next;
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }
    }

    int &operator[](int index)
    {
        return get_node(index)->value;
    }

    void insert(int val, int index)
    {
        Node *current = new Node(val);
        Node *prev = get_node(index - 1);
        Node *next = current->next;
        prev->next = current;
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList a;
    a.append(1); // Appending elements to list
    a.append(2);
    a.append(3);
    a.append(4);
    a.append(5);
    a.print(); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    a.insert(3, 1);
    a.print(); 
};
```

This gives me the error

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::range_error: IndexError: Index out of range
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: I recommend enabling all your compiler warnings, and fixing those warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to fix all of your methods, probably succeded, at least current test example is printing correct answer:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/nPThroj9W)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev; //previous node pointer
    Node(int v) : value(v), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

    Node *get_node(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0)
            throw range_error("IndexError: Index out of range");

        Node *current = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (!current)
                break;
            current = current->next;            
        }

        if (!current)
            throw range_error("IndexError: Index out of range");

        return current;
    }

public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }

    int length()
    {
        Node *current = head;
        int count = 0;

        while (current != nullptr)
        {
            count++;
            current = current->next;
        }

        cout << "Length of list is " << count << endl;
        return count;
    }

    void append(int value)
    {
        Node *new_node = new Node(value);

        if (head == nullptr)
        {
            head = new_node;
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = new_node;
            new_node->prev = tail;
            tail = new_node;
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        Node *current = head;
        cout << "[";
        if (current->next == NULL)
        {
            cout << current->value;
            cout << "]";
        }
        else
        {

            while (current->next != nullptr)
            {
                cout << current->value;
                cout << ", ";
                current = current->next;
            }
            cout << current->value << "]" << endl;
        }
    }

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        Node *current;
        Node *next;

        current = head;

        while (current != nullptr)
        {
            next = current->next;
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }
    }

    int &operator[](int index)
    {
        return get_node(index)->value;
    }

    void insert(int val, int index)
    {
        Node *node = new Node(val);
        if (index == 0) {
            if (!head) {
                head = node;
                tail = head;
            } else {
                node->next = head;
                head->prev = node;
                head = node;
            }
        } else {
            Node *prev = get_node(index - 1);
            Node *next = prev->next;
            prev->next = node;
            node->prev = prev;
            node->next = next;
            if (next)
                next->prev = node;
            if (prev == tail)
                tail = node;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList a;
    a.append(1); // Appending elements to list
    a.append(2);
    a.append(3);
    a.append(4);
    a.append(5);
    a.print(); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    a.insert(3, 1);
    a.print(); 
};
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! I am just wondering what the last part of the insert method is supposed to do? ``` if (next)
                next->prev = node;
            if (prev == tail)
                tail = node;

Comment: @N.A. There are two adjacent nodes at start `[..., prev, next, ....]`, we insert `node` between them `[..., prev, node, next, ...]`, and I update links in both directions for all 3 nodes. So it could be the case that there is no next, i.e. if `prev` is the last node, i.e. `[..., prev]` in this case `next` is `nullptr`, thus I check `if (next)`, this check just means same as `if (next != nullptr)`, because if it is null then you can't do `next->prev = ...`, because then you'll dereference null pointer, which will crash a program.

Comment: @N.A. `if (prev == tail) tail = node;` checks if `prev` was actually a tail node. If it was a tail node then I have to move tail one node further to the right, i.e. to set it to be equal to `node`. If tail wasn't at position of `prev`, then it means it was further to the right, if it is so then I don't need to update `tail`, because in this case tail doesn't move.

Answer (score 0):

Well the obvious problem in `insert` is that it calls `get_node` which tests the `size` member but nothing updates `size` anywhere.

However, fundamentally, your `append` function is wrong. It should be a class invariant that a linked list is either empty and has both its head and tail be `nullptr`s, or it should have a valid `head` and a valid `tail`.

Your `append` function does not enforce this invariant. It tries to work on two cases, one where the head is null and another where the tail is null. Ask yourself if those two cases are meaningful.

Rewrite `append` such that a list either is empty or has a valid head and tail.